# Mocking environment variables with starlette config

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, fastapi, starlette

```
from starlette.config import Config

config = Config(".env")

SOME_ENV_VAR: str = config("SOME_ENV_VAR", cast=str, default="abc")
```

I'm looking for a way to mock the value of `SOME_ENV_VAR` for unit tests. Is there such an option?

```
# mock config somehow so that config.SOME_ENV_VAR = "xyz"
def some_test():
    assert config.SOME_ENV_VAR == "xyz"
```

Comment: Since environment variables are read first by `Config` - how about setting the environment variable to the expected value before invoking the test? (for example through a fixture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's [`unittest.mock.patch` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch):

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from your_config_module import config

@patch('config.SOME_ENV_VAR', 'xyz')
def some_test():
    assert config.SOME_ENV_VAR == "xyz"
```